# Python pandas: Calculating percentage with groups using groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame which contains the information of customer type. I used `groupby` to count the type of customer within each category using following command:

```
df.groupby('Classification')['customer'].count()
```

It produces following result:

```
Classification
Agriculture     2366
Commercial     21904
Council          414
Industrial       911
Residential    51018
Name: ICP, dtype: int64
```

Now I want to calculate the percentage of each type of classification. I used follwoing command to calculate:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x/float(x.sum()))
```

But it produces following output:

```
Classification
Agriculture    100.0
Commercial     100.0
Council        100.0
Industrial     100.0
Residential    100.0
Name: ICP, dtype: float64
```

I want to show the percentage of each type of classification. Not sure where am I making the mistake. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: ``df.Classification.div(df.Classification.sum()).mul(100)``?

Comment: If all you need is the count% you can use df.groupby('Classification').value_counts(normalize = True). Its 100% because the axis =0, ie, its dividing by itself.

Comment: yep. better answer from @NickM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
df.groupby('Classification')['customer'].count()/df['customer'].count()
```